# delete "\" before pattern

Tags: sed, carriage-return

I need to delete a backslash sign with sed or awk before a pattern.
line that contain backslash is not the same into my several files
there is a carriage-return after `\`.

```
sed -r 'N;s/\([^[\]]*\n\s*AA)/\1/;P;D' file
```

file is

```
chmod 0755 /etc/test \
chmod 0777 /etc/test
```

`chmod 0777 /etc/test` is already the same line but `chmod 0755 /etc/test` change in each files. I would like to delete `\` on the first line

Comment: Just encapsulate \ into group: (\\) , and then substitute it with nothing

Comment: Why would just `sed "s/[\]//g"` not work?

Answer (score 0):

works

```
 sed -r 'N;s/\\([^\\]*\n\s*&& chown -R 82:82)/\1/;P;D' file
```

origin

```
&& chmod 0750 /tmp/htdocs/bin/cachetool.phar \
&& chown -R 82:82 /tmp/htdocs
```

after sed

```
&& chmod 0750 /tmp/htdocs/bin/cachetool.phar
&& chown -R 82:82 /tmp/htdocs
```

but I have another issue to use find with it

```
find /tmp/scripts -name file -exec sed -i 'N;s/\\([^\\]*\n\s*&& chown -R 82:82)/\1/;P;D' {} \;
```

error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a follow-up question? As an answer, it shouldn't contain another problem you've bumped into.